# Migration path from Cordova to Flutter

Tags: cordova, flutter

We have an application built with AngularJS and Cordova that needs a re-write, and we're going to work with Flutter to do it.  Googling on Migration Paths from Cordova+AngularJS to Flutter hasn't yielded any results, and we're still learning Flutter.

Is there a migration path from Cordova to Flutter?  Can we wrap our Cordova app in flutter somehow, or vice-versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Cordova cannot generate Flutter builds and I do not think there is any way to migrate Angular code to Flutter or anything to Flutter, which is a fairly new tech.

Comment: figured... oh well